# Query Features of libcurl in GNU Make

Tags: curl, makefile

I'm working on a project that requires OpenSSL to be enabled in libcurl.  The project uses GNU Make for the build system.  I'd like to add something to the Makefile to check if libcurl supports OpenSSL during the build process.

**Background**

I've discovered that the apt-get versions Curl and libcurl on different Ubuntu systems are not built with the same features.  For example, the `curl --version` command returns:

```
curl 7.27.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
```

But libcurl doesn't necessarily share those features.  I built a simple program and linked it with libcurl to get libcurl's version and found it was different.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    printf("Curl version %s\n", curl_version());
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
libcurl/7.27.0 GnuTLS/2.12.14 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
```

Further investigation showed that the apt-get version was likely built this way:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-gnutls --without-ssl
```

But I need libcurl to be built this way:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

**Summary**

Is there a way in GNU Make where I can test libcurl for OpenSSL support?  Switching to autoconf is unfortunately not an option and I've discovered that `curl-config --feature` returns the same list regardless of whether or not OpenSSL support is built in.  I've also confirmed that objdump shows differences depending on how the library was built, but I don't know if I should rely on that.

Comment: Make has no built in capability for querying things like this: that's why autoconf exists.  If you want to test this feature you'll have to write a shell command that figures it out, then you can use that in your makefile.

Comment: That's disappointing, but if that's the answer, then that's the answer.  I'll probably put a check or debug statement in the code rather than counting on a shell command.

Comment: `make` is an "old school" UNIX tool, which is designed to do one straightforward thing and provide a wealth of ways to be integrated into a larger system.  The idea is that you combine these tools in various ways that the original authors never considered, to get done what you need to do in a flexible way without writing lots of new code.  Plus, GNU make is portable across many architectures including not just POSIX and Windows, but AmigaOS, OS2, and even VMS.  Consider what it would mean to provide a concept like "test a library to see if it supports XYZ" in a cross-platform manner.